# How calculate eigenvalue, matrix without eigen function in r

Tags: r, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I want to implement eigen vectors and values without a function(eigen).

Hand calculations in simple matrices are possible, but it is hard to think about to implement them in r.

I want a code that can be used in all x matrixs (n x p).

I would be really grateful if you could provide me with an idea or code.

```
A <- t(x) %*% x 
eigen(A)$vectors # I don't want to use 'eigen' 
eigen(A)$values
```

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: I have a task of making R packages, and I want to use all the codes I use as my own code.

Comment: Try asking on crossvalidated. I think it's more suited to this kind of questiion.

Comment: `eigen` is a function in base R. Avoiding any function of base R would even mean no `+`.